# Possible Bug in Computing Surface Area of Certain Geometric Regions

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.3**

*`SphericalShell` and `CapsuleShape` are new in 10.2*

---

*Mathematica* 10.2 introduced some new geometric regions. Two of the new regions include `SphericalShell` and `CapsuleShape`. *Mathematica* seems to be having difficulty computing the surface area of both regions. For example both

```
Area @ RegionBoundary @ CapsuleShape[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1]
```

and

```
Area @ RegionBoundary @ SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4}]
```

computes indefinitely (I end up aborting the computation after about 10 minutes). I'm using *Mathematica* 10.2 on **Windows**, is this a bug or missing implementation?

Comment: I'd say missing implementation (in 10.2 it probably attempts a general symbolic CAD-based method). In fact the implementation for these has already been added in the development version. For a numerical approximation, `DiscretizeRegion` should work and give something in the ballpark of $8 \pi$ and $100 \pi$ respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until this is fixed in a future version, here is a workaround for now:

```
Unprotect[RegionBoundary];
RegionBoundary /: Area @ RegionBoundary @ SphericalShell[c_, {ri_, r_}] :=
                  Area @ Sphere[c, r] + Area @ Sphere[c, ri];
RegionBoundary /: Area @ RegionBoundary @ CapsuleShape[{v1_, v2_}, r_] :=
                  2 π r (2 r + EuclideanDistance[v2, v1]);
Protect[RegionBoundary];
```

The idea is to add the definition to `RegionBoundary` instead of `Area` to avoid returning a wrong value if one applies `Area` directly to these `3D` regions. So e.g. these

```
Area @ CapsuleShape[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1];
Area @ SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4}]
```

still correctly returns `Infinity` as they should; but with `RegionBoundary` we get:

```
Area @ RegionBoundary @ SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4}]
Area @ RegionBoundary @ CapsuleShape[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1]
```

> $100\pi$
>
> $8\pi$

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in comment by @ilian

```
acap = Area@
  RegionBoundary@DiscretizeRegion@CapsuleShape[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1]
```

> 25.0897

```
Round[acap/Pi, 1/10]*Pi
```

> 8 Pi

```
ashell = Area@
  RegionBoundary@DiscretizeRegion@SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4}]
```

> 313.472

```
Round[ashell/Pi]*Pi
```

> 100 Pi