# DiscretizeGraphics and BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics Fail on CapsuleShape and SphericalShell

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

It seems the new `Graphics3D` primitives have some incomplete features. Earlier, I uncovered a problem with computing their exact surface area see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88577/possible-bug-in-computing-surface-area-of-certain-geometric-regions). Now, I present another omission in implementation, this time with `DiscretizeGraphics` and `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` returning `EmptyRegion` and no evaluation repectively when applied to both `CapsuleShape` and `SphericalShell` e.g.

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1}]]]
```

> EmptyRegion[3]

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[CapsuleShape[]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please can anyone confirm these behaviors. I'm using *Mathematica* 10.2 on **Windows 10**

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to pass you in points. You're not allowed to participate! (As I upvote your question.) :)

Comment: @rcollyer. Okay, I'll stop participating for now :)

Comment: As long as you took my sarcasm as it was intended, then great! :)

Comment: @rcollyer, Yes I did, hence the smiley face :)

Comment: Well, maybe one day, real soon, we both can enjoy the benefits of 20k reputation.

Comment: @rcollyer, indeed I look forward to that day.

Comment: Would you like to comment/answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89407/upgrade-to-windows-10), to give those of us who haven't upgraded yet some peace of mind?

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thanks for pointing me to that question. I've answered to the best of my knowledge. Hope it helps give you some peace of mind :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Confirmed. These have already been implemented, but did not make it in time for the 10.2 release. `DiscretizeRegion` should work, however.

**Update**

Working as of *Mathematica* 10.3:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[CapsuleShape[]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]