# Upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, compatibility

Can users of *Mathematica* on Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1 upgrade their computers to Windows 10 – a process that began today? Does *Mathematica* work? Are all the settings, licenses, access to files and folders preserved? Is there anything one must be careful about?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand the vote to close; it's certainly reasonable for someone to be concerned whether he's upgrading the program or the OS it's running on.

Comment: For completeness, can you include the version of *Mathematica* you have in your question?

Comment: Mathematica 8 but I would love to know the answer to Mathematica 9 - and perhaps Mathematica 10 - as well. ;-)

Comment: Just to be sure, I think that even "partial" answers may be very helpful. Most likely, no one knows everything about possible issues with the upgrade of all possible versions of the software. But much of the partial knowledge may be generalized etc.

Comment: Magic 8-ball says: Signs point to yes. -->"Most applications and hardware drivers designed for Windows 7 or later [should work with Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/will-windows-10-be-compatible-with-mathematica/4cadefcb-2f66-4c5c-a22c-5f8289550cea)."

Comment: @dionys, notice the "most" and "should"… some amount of wiggle room still left. :)

Comment: @J. M. -- Yes, pretty standard corporate answer, but I guess it indicates they are making an effort to match Win7 compatibility.

Comment: [There's at least one regular on this site using M 10.2 on Windows 10.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88639/12)

Comment: I used *Mathematica* 10 on an earlier build of Windows 10 (in a VirtualBox). Worked smoother than on Win 7.

Comment: I observed a strange behavior on Windows 10, mma 10.2. Sometimes, mma freezes on start, and VS comes out to ask for debugging. At this moment the cursor moves extremely slow. But after terminating mma, everything goes back to normal.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I can confirm that upgrading to **Windows 10** from either **Windows 7** or **Windows 8.1** (you can't upgrade from **Windows 8** directly, you first have to upgrade to **8.1**) leaves all your settings and licenses intact and that includes your *Mathematica* (9, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2) installation, I didn't have version 8 installed but I would guess it should work too. I have also noticed that *Mathematica* performs better on Windows 10 than in previous Windows versions. **Windows 10** will preserve your files and folders, just select that option when upgrading. I've tried this on up to four PCs (including a laptop and an AIO), installation was smooth and every program works fine so far.

One thing to note is that with **Windows 10**, you should make sure your graphics drivers (I only have NVIDIA) are updated to the **WHQL**-certified versions, I know for sure this will affect *Mathematica*, if it's not updated. The drivers should/will be updated during your upgrade so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I just upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10 and computed 2+3 on Mathematica 9. ;-)

Comment: @LubošMotl. Nice :) Glad to hear it. Hope you're enjoying the new interface.

Comment: @LubošMotl You'll get better results with 10 on 10! lol :-D

Comment: I surely do enjoy it! Ho1: Win 10 is called 10 but it's *actually* a 9, too. ;-) If Stephen Wolfram sends me an upgrade again, I won't refuse, however.

Answer (score 18):

I upgraded three machines from Windows 7 to Windows 10, two of which were work machines containing installations of Mathematica 10.x (and earlier). So far I have encountered zero issues related to Mathematica with this Windows upgrade. From a personal perspective, upgrading to Windows 10 was very simple.

Also the QA team for Mathematica did a full test of Mathematica 10.2 on Windows 10 (and a prerelease version of it). There was one issue found related to STL and PLY import, but that was fixed before the 10.2 release.

Windows 10 was added to the list of supported platforms:

http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html

If you encounter any issues related specifically to Mathematica and Windows 10 (and not with the Windows 10 upgrade process itself), please do contact support@wolfram.com. If you (accidentally or intentionally) do a clean installation of Windows 10, you will need to reinstall Mathematica and you will need to reactivate it.

Comment: In windows 10 ListBox command doesn't work properly

Comment: @TraceKira We've looked into this and this is a problem on all platforms in Mathematica 10.2, although it seems to only happen sporadically.

Comment: @TraceKira Thank you for your feedback here and on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/546508). This `ListPicker` issue is a bug that affects *Mathematica* 10.2 on all platforms, and is definitely not specific to Windows 10.